# Fail subscription to Orion change contest from Node Server

Tags: node.js, server, request, fiware, fiware-orion

I am developing a simple project in which I made a list of entities that I put on Orion-LD. Now I would like to make a server that allows to receive notifications whenever the state of an entity attribute changes. i chose to use Node.JS Express for ease but it is not mandatory.
I am leaving here the simple code used to implement my server.

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

//Subscription on batteryLevel changes of device 9845A
app.get('/subscribe', (req, res) => {
    const data = {
        "description": "Subscription",
        "subject": {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Device:9845A",
                    "type": "Device"
                }
            ],
            "condition": {
                "attrs": ["batteryLevel"]
            }
        },
        "notification": {
            "http": {
                "url": `http://localhost:${PORT}/notification`
            },
            "attrsFormat" : "keyValues"
        }
    };
      
    const options = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        json: data
    };

    request.post('http://localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions', options, (error, response, request) => {
        console.log(response.body);
        res.end("Succesfully subscribed!");
    });
});

// Listen on notification
app.post('/notification', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Notification received:', req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${PORT}`)
});
```

This is implementation of `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  # Orion-LD Context Broker
  orion:
    container_name: fiware-orion
    image: fiware/orion:latest
    hostname: orion
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
    expose:
      - "1026"
    ports:
      - "1026:1026"
    command: -dbhost mongo-db -logLevel DEBUG
    networks:
      - default
  
  # Database
  mongo-db:
    container_name: fiware-mongo
    image: mongo:4.4
    hostname: mongo-db
    expose:
      - "27017"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: --nojournal
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongo-db:/data
    networks:
      - default
  
  # Server
  node-server:
    container_name: fiware-node
    build: .
    hostname: node-server
    depends_on:
      - orion
    expose:
      - "3000"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./data/node:/data
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - iot-sensors
          - context-provider

  # RDF Store
  virtuoso:
    container_name: fiware-virtuoso
    image: openlink/virtuoso-opensource-7:latest
    ports:
      - "1111:1111"
      - "8890:8890"
    environment:
      SPARQL_UPDATE: true
      DBA_PASSWORD: dba
    volumes:
      - ./data/virtuoso:/data

networks:
  default:
```

This is `Dockerfile` related to Node.js Express:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY server/package*.json server/server.js ./
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

The problem is that if I subscribe to an existing entity properly, it reports a `"status": "failed"` in the subscription and therefore I cannot receive notifications about the status. Reading the Orion LD logs, it seems that it can't communicate with my server at port `3000`, but I can't figure out why. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If a notification failed, you will probably have some indication in Orion-LD's logs.
Also, assuming you're using docker, is the port 3000 "open", so that the broker can connect to it?

Comment: The docker log say that couldn't connect to server, even if the port is opened. I can't understand why. I'm simply creating a server on port 3000 that works but orion ld can't communicate with it. Maybe I am making a mistake in creating the docker?

Comment: Could you perhaps show your Dockerfile. Are you using docker-compose?

Comment: Seems to be some kind of networking problem. Maybe related with the docker setup.

Comment: Yes i'm updating with my dockerfile and docker-compose

Comment: Okay i solved the issue. The problem was that I was trying to access the node server through localhost, but it was in the same container as Orion and so couldn't reach it. So I simply solved it by accessing the ` fiware-node:3000` address that I defined for the node service.

Comment: According to StackOverflow style, I'd suggest to move the solution in your comment above to a self-answer to your question post.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. The problem was that I was trying to access the node server through localhost, but it was in the same container as Orion and so couldn't reach it. So I simply solved it by accessing the `fiware-node:3000` address that I defined for the node service.